# Inconsistent InputFilter behaviour while inserting a new-line character

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

Given this method signature from [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter#filter(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20android.text.Spanned,%20int,%20int)):

```
public abstract CharSequence filter (CharSequence source, 
            int start, 
            int end, 
            Spanned dest, 
            int dstart, 
            int dend)
```

and these attributes set on `EditText`:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Suppose we have a text `FooBar` inside our `EditText` (set with the attributes mentioned above). When placing cursor between these two words (`Foo|Bar`) and pressing `Enter`, we get:

```
source = "\n",
start = 0,
end = 0

dstart = 3,
dend = 3,
dest = "FooBar"
```

As you see, new-line character `"\n"` is inserted at the cursor position. This is somewhat expected and this is good. I just need to detect this insertion and but ignore it by returning `""` instead of `"\n"`.

Let's start again. Suppose we have a text `FooBar` inside our `EditText`. Let's place our cursor between these two words (`Foo|Bar`) and type *123*. Now you should have `Foo123|Bar`. Then press `Enter`.

This is what I expect:

```
source = "\n",
start = 0,
end = 0

dstart = 6,
dend = 6,
dest = "Foo123Bar"
```

As before, I would then return `""` instead of `"\n"`. But stop. This is what I actually got:

```
source = "",
start = 0,
end = 0

dstart = 6,
dend = 9,
dest = "Foo123Bar"
```

Why do `InputFilter` behaviour differ? I might misunderstand something, but this seems to be an inconsistent behaviour. Any idea how to fix it? Or maybe there is an explanation to that.

Inside `InputFilter`, I need a way to detect a new-line character insertion command, then replace this character by an empty string.

Any help will be very appreciated!